# php in_array is not working

Tags: php, arrays

Can you please help me in below code.
In the below code, in_array is not working.

```
$d = "23232,54454,656565";
$data = explode(",", $d);
$pass = (isset($test['pass'][1]) ? $test['pass'][1] : '');
if(in_array($pass, $data)) {
  echo "exist";
} else {
  echo "Not Exist";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you are passing $test['pass'] array of string and want to address the first element of an array than you should use $test['pass'][0]. But if you are addressing the second element of $test['pass'] array than your code looks correct.

Comment: It is working exactly how it should work. In line 3 `$pass` value is ` ` empty string and if condition fail. Where from the `$test['pass']` comes? Make sure it contain the right value. Debug if before if condition to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

i tested your code and put following line to top of that and it work:

```
$test['pass'][1] = '23232';
```

$test['pass'][1] is empty and you see "Not Exist" message